# How do you set a polygon layers transparency in DotSpatial

Tags: vb.net, dotspatial

How do you set a polygon layers transparency in DotSpatial?

I'm using vb.net in visual studio express 2013 and using a Dotspatial nugets package which has given me DotSpatial version 1.7.

Please see my code below in how i'm currently adding a new polygon shape to a dotspatial map control (mpMain), colouring it blue with a black outline.

```
shp = New Data.Shapefile
shp.FeatureType = Topology.FeatureType.Polygon
shp.Name = "CoveragePolygon"
shp.AddFeature(New DotSpatial.Topology.Polygon(m_coverCoords))
Dim mpl As DotSpatial.Controls.MapPolygonLayer
mpl = mpMain.Layers.Add(shp)
mpl.Symbolizer = New DotSpatial.Symbology.PolygonSymbolizer(Color.Blue, Color.Black)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out seconds after posting, you need to specify a colour using the Color.FromArgb method making sure you specify the desired alpha transparency then the base colour i.e.

```
mpl.Symbolizer = New DotSpatial.Symbology.PolygonSymbolizer(Color.FromArgb(50,Color.Blue), Color.Black)
```